# Usemin and multiple build configurations

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-usemin

Following is the sample usemin build configuration in my index.html file

```
<!-- build:js js/one.js -->
<script src="app/modules/one/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/two.js -->
<script src="app/modules/two/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

For development version, I dont want to minify the scripts and i want each module into its own js file. So the index.html after running would be

```
<script src="js/one.js"></script>
<script src="js/two.js"></script>
```

For production version,I want to minify the scripts and concat them into a single file.So the index.html would be

```
<script src="js/myApp.js"></script>
```

I tried the following , but it is not working:

```
<!-- build:myApp js/myApp.js -->
<!-- build:js js/one.js -->
<script src="app/modules/one/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/two.js -->
<script src="app/modules/two/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And run the use-min task like this (prod would be set to true in the prod task and false in dev task) -

```
usemin({
          myApp: prod?[uglify({mangle:true})]:'',
          js: prod?'':[uglify({mangle:false})]
      }).
```

I can keep two index.html files and manage this.But I was wondering can this be achieved with a single index.html?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using the same pipeline id: **js**

```
 <!-- build:js js/one.js -->
 <!-- build:js js/two.js -->
```

Try using unique pipeline ids like so:

```
 <!-- build:js1 js/one.js -->
 <!-- build:js2 js/two.js -->
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Merge all javascript files in 2 files like in your dev env. After that just merge those two files into one big?

```
<!-- build:js js/one.js -->
<script src="app/modules/one/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/two.js -->
<script src="app/modules/two/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:myApp js/myApp.js -->
<script src="js/one.js"></script>
<script src="js/two.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Or even marge all files with one build?

```
<!-- build:myApp js/myApp.js -->
<script src="app/modules/one/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/one/three.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/one.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/two.js"></script>
<script src="app/modules/two/three.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..But how to dynamically setup such a configuration with a single index.html because I hate to keep two sets of build configuration manually

Comment: Why do you have two index files at first place? Can we see the full config?

Comment: No. I have only a single index file